# Remote Debugging Java application not show variable values

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I have a .java file which I deploy to a server and debug it through my local eclipse . I have started application by command

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y TestRemoteDebug
```

I have created proper debug configuration in eclipse too .

Now when i start application I can see that it hits breakpoints but I cant see any of variable values in Variable pane or by hovering over variable as it works in local machine .

Any help appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling the java file with `javac -g`  fixed this .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you have to set up maven-compile-plugin

```
        <!-- Compilation management -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>               
            </configuration>            
        </plugin>
```